# What are pros and cons of Voronoi shatter?

Tags: algorithm

I have seen [some Voronoi shatter videos on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=voronoi+shatter&aq=f).

What is your experience with it?

What are the pros and cons in time complexity, resource complexity, implementation difficulty...?

Does it emulate how a real material would react?

Comment: Not sure why this is voted to close. It seems like a decent, real question.

Comment: Do you have some paper about this topic? It looks really interesting :)

Comment: Remember with game development it's always about approximating the real world, you aren't trying to create reality - just fool someone into thinking that it is. You simply don't have enough processing power to create a perfect reality.

Comment: The way it's phrased isn't really a question.  Pros: Cool looking shatter.  Cons: You have to pay for it with compute time.

Comment: Tend to agree.  "What are the pros and cons" questions are meaningless unless you're comparing against something else.

Answer (score 3):

As to the last question: It doesn't emulate most of real-world materials aside from very few exceptions, and these only for some specific choices of the Voronoi cell seeds. For example, [toughened glass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toughened_glass) shatters like this, since the material is "pre-broken" into a loosely-held Voronoi-like structure in the process of manufacturing it.

On the other hand, state of the art particle systems don't usually emulate explosion dynamics, fluid flow in a waterfall or fog dispersion either ...

Comment: It doesn't simulate real-world materials, but it does emulate them, as the idea is to imitate real-world physics.

Comment: @3nixios Could you please elaborate on the difference you see between emulate & simulate ?

Comment: @Takhiarel A simulation is when you try to simulate exactly how things will happen in a real situation. The idea is to reproduce the events that lead to a final situation. The difference with emulation is that you are focused on the end result and not the means to get there.

Comment: @3nixios: Thing is, Voronoi shatter patterns don't look like most real-world material shatter patterns. Neither do particle explosions, for example - they emulate CINEMATIC explosions, not real-world ones. That said, they often look good enough and are certainly fast enough.

Comment: I guess the difference between simulation and emulation can be a bit meaningless when the base isn't 'real'. Is ot not possible to emulate real world materials though?

Comment: @3nixios: You used the word "simulate" in your definition of the word "simulation". While I know what you mean, I think the better option would have been "mimic". But we're getting into english.stackexchange.com territory here!

Comment: @Nick Wiggill: But "emulate" has more of the "mimic" meaning, since I can emulate someone whom I admire, but I wouldn't "simulate" him, unless I was trying to create a cyborg clone of him.